# how to convert 13 digit unix milliseconds to hour only in java

Tags: java, time

How to convert 13 digit unix timestamp to hour?

ex: **1567024014000**

want to convert above value in hours only using select SQL
Query or using java.

Comment: What do you mean by *hours only*? Do you want to extract the time of day of that particular instant or do anything else?

Comment: If you mean hour of day (or clock hour of AM or PM), in which time zone then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the hours of the full datetime represented by those epoch milliseconds by converting it to an object representing this moment in time and then use an offset or a time zone to get a specific date and time of day:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long millis = 1567024014000L;
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalTime lt = odt.toLocalTime();
    System.out.printf("epoch millis %d represent the time of day %s",
            millis, lt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Full datetime representation is %s and hours only would be %d",
            odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), lt.getHour());
}
```

The output is

```
epoch millis 1567024014000 represent the time of day 20:26:54
Full datetime representation is 2019-08-28T20:26:54Z and hours only would be 20
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to extract the hour of the day:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1567024014000L);
int hour = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour(); // 20
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy in Java:

```java
public final class UnixTimestampConverterUtils {

    public static long unixToJavaTime(long utime) {
        return utime * 1000;
    }

    public static long javaToUnixTime(long ms) {
        return ms / 1000;
    }

}
```

Then you can extract hours using e.g. `Calendar` or `LocalDateTime`.